# Save file from video stream via VLC by parts

Tags: bash, video-streaming, vlc

I saving video stream from camera to file using VLC like this:

```
cvlc -vvv rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx --sout '#transcode{vcodec="h263"}:standart{mux="ts",access="file",dst="cam_XXX_hour_$(date +%H).ts"}'
```

So at the end of the day broadcast I expected to see a few files, like:

```
cam_XXX_hour_05.ts
cam_XXX_hour_06.ts
....
cam_XXX_hour_23.ts
cam_XXX_hour_24.ts
```

But it's not. I've got one BIG file named by first hour while VLC start.
How can I get the desired result? Any BASH or VLC/VLM setting? 
(I'm planning to port this script to VLM schedule)

Even if not by time, then by max file size..

Thanks.

P.S. Please, do not offer to split a large file at the end of the day.

Comment: If vlc could do that (and it really CAN do much), I would be out of business...  I guess that you'll have to find some other app for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find automatic solution for this problem, but got a key idea:

1. Create VLM config with start file:

   new cam broadcast enabled

   setup cam input rtsp://xxx:xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/xxx

   setup cam output #transcode{vcodec="h264"}:std{mux=ts,dst=/xxx/FIRST_FILE}

   control cam play
2. Change file via telnet interface (by cron or some script)

   setup cam output #transcode{vcodec="h264"}:std{mux=ts,dst=/xxx/SECOND_FILE}

   control cam stop

   control cam play

Two controls commands needed for update VLM config.